# French 70s-style commercial font identification

Tags: fonts, font-identification, font-design

I'm looking for the name of a font which was quite commonly used on storefronts in France during the late 70s / early 80s (I guess). I'm also interested in some history and/or trivia about this font if you have some.

Here is a legacy exemple I've found recently:
[image: A legacy storefront with the researched font]

And the subtitle of this 1983 printed document found on Wikipedia show the same font, or at least the same style. ("Grand Réseau Sud 5e 6e 14e")
[image: Printed Document exemple]

I got no success with the WhatTheFont research engine.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What The Font found [Jackson MN](https://www.myfonts.com/products/jackson-jackson-321704?queryId=fd97324c88f76efcfde83573260b6b87&index=universal_search_data&objectIDs=8655530001)

[image]

Often the trick with What The Font is a tight crop, or even monochrome, with or without inverting colours. This one worked with just the crop.

Comment: Great! It's exactly this! (OK I must clean up a bit the picture before using What The Font).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Tetsujin's anwser, I have found https://jacksonmnr.com/publications, a project gathering all the legacy usages of Jackson MN in France and western Europe in general. This is deliciously retro!